# Emulating the right Ctrl key on MacBook Pro keyboard lacking an actual right Ctrl key

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro, remapping

I need to use the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key in a certain application, but my keyboard doesn't have one.

The left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key has an entirely different function in this case. How can I emulate the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, for example by pressing the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> button?

I tried the “Right Option acts as Control” feature of [DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/), but sadly, that causes the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to emulate the *left* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key instead of the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Aaargh!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found the solution: [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) has an <kbd>Option_R</kbd> to <kbd>Control_R</kbd> feature

Comment: KeyRemap4MacBook has been renamed to [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en).

Comment: Worked for me too to get my cursor out of VirtualBox running in a CentOS VM where I'm connected to via VNC.

Comment: In 2023 this is still the way to go

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> worked for me. Here's what you can do.

- Go to `Keyboard Preferences` on your mac
- Check the box that says :

  ```
  Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys
  ```

OR

- Else You have to Press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> every time.

Answer (score 0):

This little app http://www.manytricks.com/keycodes/ claims to show the keycodes (I haven't got a mac to try it out on) your looking for some way of generating keycode 109 I think.  You could see if any combination produces that.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, but I have the same problem on a new macbook pro.
I found Mathias Bynens' answer and installed Karabiner, but I would like not to remap optionn to control because I need the right option key to type all special characters in the left-hand side of the keyboard (which I use quite a lot).

My solution was to remap the left arrow key to control using the "Simple modifications" pane on Karabiner (`left_arrow` to `right_control`), and then mapped `control` + `right_arrow` to `left_arrow` using the complex modification below.

So now `right control` is where my fingers expect it to be, next to option and command, and to use `right arrow` I press and hold the actual right arrow key (i.e. `right control`) and then use the `left arrow` key.

Here is the complex modification (to use it, just copy it in a new file in the configuration directory of Karabiner under assets/complex_modifications).

```
{
  "title": "Ctrl + right arrow to left arrow",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "Ctrl + right arrow to left arrow",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "from": {
            "key_code": "right_arrow",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "right_control"
              ],
              "optional": [
                "caps_lock",
                "option",
                "command",
                "shift",
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "left_arrow"
            }
          ],
          "type": "basic"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got other choices as well:

1. Use an external usb keyboard, that has got the right ctrl key
2. Change the right ctrl key to the left ctrl key, in your application.

For eg. VirtualBox comes with right ctrl key mapped as the host key, by default. But you can right click the key icon at the bottom right window corner and choose keyboard settings and then change the host key to left ctrl key or just ctrl key.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1162123)

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>Right cmd</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> (left arrow)

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (<kbd>Return</kbd>) works on my Macbook pro for <kbd>right-ctrl</kbd>