# MacVim with Mac Keyboard: Where Is the Right CTRL Key?

Tags: macos, keyboard, vim, macvim, keymap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Emulating the ‘right ctrl’ key on MacBook Pro keyboard (which lacks an actual ‘right ctrl’ key)](https://superuser.com/questions/48362/emulating-the-right-ctrl-key-on-macbook-pro-keyboard-which-lacks-an-actual-ri)

I can't seem to find it... and I want to use it for MacVim to facilitate typing `CTRL-W` for window commands. What is the standard solution? Should I map a key on the right side of the keyboard to CTRL? I want something standard so that I can be most proficient when pairing on another computer.

Comment: Which keyboard - I use a standard Apple wired one and it has a right hand ctrl key

Comment: Mac laptop keyboards and the smaller wireless keyboards (w/o numeric keypad) have no right control key.

Comment: About to delete my answer and vote to close this as a duplicate -- consider using your caps lock key as your control key, or look at the other question which this duplicates.