# Ctrl + W is awkward

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Emulating the right Ctrl key on MacBook Pro keyboard lacking an actual right Ctrl key](https://superuser.com/questions/48362/emulating-the-right-ctrl-key-on-macbook-pro-keyboard-lacking-an-actual-right-ctr)
>   [MacVim with Mac Keyboard: Where Is the Right CTRL Key?](https://superuser.com/questions/235305/macvim-with-mac-keyboard-where-is-the-right-ctrl-key)

I'm fairly new to Vim and I learned that if I want to switch which window I'm working in, I need to press Ctrl + W, followed by a h, j, k, or l.  "Ctrl + W" is a really awkward series of keypresses -- at least on a Mac -- for such a common command.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MacVim with Mac Keyboard: Where Is the Right CTRL Key?](http://superuser.com/questions/235305/macvim-with-mac-keyboard-where-is-the-right-ctrl-key) and/or [Emulating the right Ctrl key on MacBook Pro keyboard lacking an actual right Ctrl key](http://superuser.com/questions/48362/emulating-the-right-ctrl-key-on-macbook-pro-keyboard-lacking-an-actual-right-ctr)

Comment: I just remap ctrl to caps

Answer (score 6):

`<C-W><C-W>` will jump to the next window below or right, and after the last window it cycles back to the first, so if you're not using very many windows, you can just hold one finger on the `Ctrl` key and hit the `W` key until you get to the window you want. See

```
:help CTRL-W_CTRL-W
```

Answer (score 5):

`<C-W><C-J>` is an alternative to `<C-W>j` but that's all there is according to the docs (see `:h ^Wj`)

You may define your own mapping like this

`:map <F2> <C-W>j`

Comment: Remapping is quite useful when other programs capture the shortcut. Such as logging in via ssh on Google Cloud Engine in a browser: there ctrl-w will close the browser tab ..